# How to pass a keyed array from hook_menu() into a page_callback using page_arguments?

Tags: arrays, forms, drupal-7, argument-passing, hook-form-alter

I have implemented a hook_menu() and calling a function with page_callback in it.

I can pass arguments there by using function bla_form($var) definition. When I return a call to `return drupal_get_form('bla_node_form', $new_node, $project_id)` I get my $var in `$form_state['args'][1]`.

If I pass `array(4)` I get `$form_state['args'][1]`.

If I pass `array('project_id' => 4)` I get `$form_state['args'][1]['project_id']`.

I'd like to get `$form_state['args']['project_id']`.

EXAMPLE:

```
function form_example_menu () {
  $items['node/add/bla/project/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => '_bla_form',
    'page arguments' => array(4),//This is where I want to pass a keyed array!!!
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
  return $items;
}
function _bla_form ($project_id = array()) {
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
  $new_node = new stdClass;
  $new_node->type = 'bla';
  $new_node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
  return drupal_get_form('bla_node_form', $new_node, $project_id);
}
```

As a workaround: if i can not do it this way: how can i make sure if I reading $form_state['args'] that I'm using the proper element to get my argument (not that some other one)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use "Auto-Loader Wildcards". More info in the section of the same name on the hook_menu documentation page: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7

Then in your path you could have "%project" instead of the simple "%", then create the "project_load($project_id)" function that would return the array you want. That array would then be the one you get in the first parameter of you page callback.